# Implement temperature in my windows phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, weather, weather-api

Hey I want to implement the current temperature of current location into my application.
there is in my app I want to show  one TextBlock and it shows current temperature of current location of user. how it possible?? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just get the `temperature`. You should use a weather API to retrieve all the weather forecast for a particular location.

For example you could get a weather API from [here](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx).

Have a look at these:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Weather_in_Windows_Phone_7

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=485

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's possible to add local weather to application. There is some apps which include local whether like 
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/night-stand-clock/19c2c6c3-6eeb-df11-9264-00237de2db9e
please help me.